# Can someone help explain the Fisher Yates Array Shuffle

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

So I am trying to get an understanding for array shuffling.

I came across this article:
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

But I am confused.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Here are my questions:

On line 2 "m" is defined, but I don't understand why "t" and "i" are part of that definition.  Are "t" and "i" being defined as true?

The while loop condition is: "as long as m=true".  However, as far as I can tell, nothing happens to the length of the array, so won't it stay true indefinitely?

The last part of my confusion is this:

```
  t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
```

So "t" equals a value in the array.  "m" is the length of the array and this tells "t" which value to choose.

Then that value is replaced with another value in the array.  This new value uses the previously generated random number to choose a different value (I can't tell if there is a possibility to choose the same value).

This new value is re-defined as "t".  This part I just don't understand.

It almost seems to be looping in on itself with array[i] = t and the whole thing starting all over again.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are swapping array elements into a new order to do the shuffle. `m` indicates the element you are moving. `t` is temporary storage used in the swap. That is why one-letter variable names are generally avoided. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) has a good explanation of the technique.

Comment: Start this code in your debugger and step line by line through it to see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

That code is indeed confusing. It would be better to declare variables right where they belong. Does this make more sense?

```
function shuffle(array) {
    let m = array.length

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m)

        m--

        // And swap it with the current element.
        let temp = array[m]
        array[m] = array[i]
        array[i] = temp
    }

    return array
}
```

Comment: Hello!

Yes that helps a bit.

I am still confused by this:

```
let temp = array[m]
        array[m] = array[i]
        array[i] = temp
```

Comment: ```let temp = array[m]```

So we declare "temp" with the value from the end of the array.
I understand this as "m" being the full length initially but it decreases with each pass-through of the while loop.

```array[m] = array[i]```

After, it seems like we are re-assigning that same value from the array with a randomly chosen one via the random number.

```array[i] = temp```

This part confuses me.  It looks like we are re-assigning "array[i]" to be "temp", but wouldn't that just mean it has the value of "array[m]" and ultimately "array[i]" ?

Comment: As an example: 

Say the initial length of the array is 10.

Say the value at 4 is "x" and the value at 9 is "y".

So at this point m=10

The random number generated is 4 so array[4] would have a value of "y".

m-- means m goes from 10 to 9.

temp = the value at array[9] which is "y".

Then array[9] becomes array[4] which is "x".

Lastly, array [4] becomes "temp" which is array[9].

So didn't we just go into a loop with no real change?

Comment: ` "temp" which is array[9]` - this is not correct. An assignment creates a copy of the value, so after `a=something; b=a` , `b` contains the same value as `a`, but it is not related to `a` in any way. In your example, in `a[i]=temp`, `temp` is `x`, not `array[9]`.

Comment: Oh is that so?  Then for clarity's sake, what would the value of array[i] be from my example?  "y" ?

Comment: here's a simpler question: let A be `[1,2]`. After `x=A[1]` and then `x=99`, what will A contain?

Comment: let A = [1,2]; 
let x = A[1] (which is the value 2); 
x = 99; 

A still equals [1,2] ?